# Slow printing to HP Laserjet 6MP with 12.04

Tags: 12.04, printing, hp, hplip, laserjet

What can I do to print faster?

My Laserjet 6MP has the max amount of memory. Connected directly to Ubuntu PC, via LPT.
It was printing faster with Windows 2000.

Comment: What version of **HPLIP** is installed? (type: **dpkg -l | grep hplip**) Is this a new install of **12.04** or an update?

Comment: Is this connecting over USB or parallel ?

Comment: The original 6MP has only Parallel port. It is connected via LPT

Answer (score 0):

It can work under **Ubuntu 12.04**, but with some issues:

[HP Laserjet 6MP prints blank test page in Ubuntu 12.04 Precise](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/990158)

[HP Linux Imaging and Printing >> HP LaserJet 6mp Printer](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/laserjet/hp_laserjet_6mp.html)

Sorry, I haven't used an HP 6MP for several years, and forget its nuances ..

Comment: HP LJ 6MP is a very good printer. Nothing special. Just LPT. 600x600 dpi. Installer for Ubuntu 12.04 available. Why costs printing a 1 page PDF 4 minutes?